# Consulta retorna vazio utilizando PHP com PDO e MS SQLServer

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

Estou migrando um sistema feito em ASP para PHP. 
Porém, estou com problemas na hora de fazer umaconsulta usando o PDO:

**Busca.php**

```
class Busca extends Conexao {

    private $termo;

    public function setTermo($termo) { $this->termo = $termo; }
    public function getTermo() { return $this->termo; }

    public function listarResultados() {
        try {
            $pdo = parent::getDB();
            $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT D2.D2CDORG AS COD_ORGAO, D2.D2DSORG AS NME_ORGAO, D1.D1CDSRV AS COD_SERVICO, D1.D1DSSRV AS NME_SERVICO, D3.D3CDITM AS COD_ITEM, D3.D3DSITM AS NME_ITEM, D3.D3VALOR * (SELECT D7VLREAL FROM D7VRTE WHERE D7AAMMREF = 11) AS VALOR FROM D5ITMORGSRV D5, D3ITENS D3, D2ORGAOS D2, D1SERVICOS D1 WHERE (D1.D1CDSRV <> 5) AND (D5.D1CDSRV = D1.D1CDSRV) AND (D5.D2CDORG = D2.D2CDORG) AND (D5.D3CDITM = D3.D3CDITM) AND ((D3.D3DSITM LIKE :termo) OR (D1.D1DSSRV LIKE :termo)) ORDER BY NME_ORGAO, NME_SERVICO, NME_ITEM");
            $consulta->bindValue(':termo', $this->getTermo());
            $consulta->execute();
            return $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'><b>Ocorreu um erro: </b>" . $e->getMessage() ."</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

**Página de Resultados:**

```
$busca = new Busca;
$busca->setTermo('identidade');
$resultado = new ArrayIterator($busca->listarResultados());
```

**O retorno é:**

```
SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Campo COUNT incorreto ou erro de sintaxe (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:133)
```

Pesquisando, vi que é no `bindValue`, mas já tentei de tudo e nada funciona.

Tentei usar dois `bindValue` (`:termo1` e `:termo2`). Não dá o erro acima, mas retorna `ArrayIterator Object ( )` no `print_r`.

Se no lugar de `:termo` eu passar '`%identidade%`', por exemplo, os dados são mostrados corretamente.

**Assim funciona:** (`LIKE '%".$this->getTermo()."%'`)

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT D2.D2CDORG AS COD_ORGAO, D2.D2DSORG AS NME_ORGAO, D1.D1CDSRV AS COD_SERVICO, D1.D1DSSRV AS NME_SERVICO, D3.D3CDITM AS COD_ITEM, D3.D3DSITM AS NME_ITEM, D3.D3VALOR * (SELECT D7VLREAL FROM D7VRTE WHERE D7AAMMREF = 11) AS VALOR FROM D5ITMORGSRV D5, D3ITENS D3, D2ORGAOS D2, D1SERVICOS D1 WHERE (D1.D1CDSRV <> 5) AND (D5.D1CDSRV = D1.D1CDSRV) AND (D5.D2CDORG = D2.D2CDORG) AND (D5.D3CDITM = D3.D3CDITM) AND ((D3.D3DSITM LIKE '%".$this->getTermo()."%') OR (D1.D1DSSRV LIKE '%".$this->getTermo()."%')) ORDER BY NME_ORGAO, NME_SERVICO, NME_ITEM");
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Quando passou  `:termo1` e `:termo2` colocou o `%` na consulta ou no `bindvalue()`?

Comment: Na consulta. Mas mesmo assim não funciona. Tentei usar `?` ao inves de `:termo`. Não muda nada..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passe os coringas no `bindValue()`, não deixe eles na consulta senão serão escapados e então sua consulta falhará.

Parece que o driver do SQL Server tem um detalhe, não permite utilizar o mesmo valor para mais de um identificador, para resolver isso defina um novo placeholder.

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela 
                           WHERE nome like :termo1 OR descricao like :termo2");
$consulta->bindValue(':termo1', '%'.$this->getTermo().'%');
$consulta->bindValue(':termo2', '%'.$this->getTermo().'%');
```

Ou ainda:

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome like ? OR descricao like ?");
$consulta->execute('%'.$this->getTermo().'%', '%'.$this->getTermo().'%');
```

Comment: Certo, só que eu tenho o `:termo` duas vezes na query. Precisarei usar `bindValue(:termo1)` e `bindValue(:termo1)` com o mesmo valor?

Comment: Em teoria se eles tem o mesmo valor, então faça um bind só. Agora se retornar `SQLSTATE[07002]` isso é uma indicação que vai precisar de dois. Teste ai retorna aqui :) @buback

Comment: Sim.. foi nessa que deu o `07002`. Achei que tinha um jeito de usar o mesmo bind já que tem o mesmo valor. Mas obrigado.

Comment: @buback, parecer ser algo especifico do driver do SQL Server, fiz o teste no MySQL(é o unico que tenho aqui) funcinou com um bind só. Então recomendo trocar o `:termo` por duas `?` e passar os `%` também.

`$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela 
                           WHERE nome like ? OR descricao like ?");
$consulta->bindValue(1, '%'.$this->getTermo().'%');
$consulta->bindValue(2, '%'.$this->getTermo().'%');`

Comment: É.. é isso que estou fazendo. Pois é, no MySQL eu também já usei o mesmo bind pra dois where e funcionou normal. Valeu! ;)

Comment: Deu certo repetindo a `?` @buback

Comment: Deu certo, eu estou usando assim. Acho que é o Drive do SQLServer mesmo. Vou tentar atualizá-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando meta-caracteres '%', '%' Corresponde a qualquer número de caracteres, até mesmo zero caractere

```
$busca = new Busca;
$busca->setTermo('%identidade%');
$resultado = new ArrayIterator($busca->listarResultados());
```

LIKE ‘__a%’
Vai ser buscado todos os itens que tenham a letra a na quarta posição da palavra.

LIKE ‘%a’
Palavras terminadas em a.

LIKE ‘a%’
Palavras começadas em a.

LIKE ‘a%b%c’
Palavra deve começar com a, ter no meio b e terminar com c.

NOT LIKE ‘%@%’
not like é retornado todos os dados que não tenham o valor definido nele, no caso, retorna tudo que não tenha @

campo LIKE ‘%@%’
Retorna todos os dados que tenham o valor definido nele, no caso, retorna tudo que tenha @

Exemplo:

SELECT * FROM `tb_php` WHERE campo LIKE “%a%”

Comment: Muito obrigado. Como tem o mesmo valor, achei que houvesse uma forma de usar o mesmo bind.